# Layout-land folder is not changing the display on an emulator

Tags: android

I'm having a problem making my emulator switch to a landscape layout, as shown by the screenshot below i have defined a landscape layout folder, with the files in it. I'm not sure if the problem is to do with the fact they are fragments but i'm unsure.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i41RZ.png)
Manifext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="apackage.test.freelanceproject">
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Start of fragment1.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Page1Fragment">
```

Start of fragment (landscape) xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Page1Fragment">
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
android: configChanges = "orientation|screenSize"
//This means you will handle the configuration change yourself, 
//the activity wont't restart automatically when device orientation changed
```

so you could delete this line.

Comment: For some reason this still does not work. For all accounts my code should now work so i'm not sure what is happening